# CrashPlan only loads from terminal, not desktop

Tags: crashplan

I couldn't find this particular problem I'm having, so here it goes.

On Ubuntu 14.04, I can successfully launch CrashPlan by typing `sudo CrashPlan` or `sudo /usr/local/crashplan/bin/CrashPlanDesktop`.

However, when I try to click on the Launcher CrashPlan icon or the desktop icon, nothing happens. The program does not launch. It only works via terminal, for some reason.

What can I do to make the icons work?

Comment: You might want to examine permissions on `/usr/local/crashplan/bin/CrashPlanDesktop`

Comment: @DavidF: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: OK, I converted it to an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CrashPlan desktop does not require sudo (or gksudo in the case of the graphical launcher). Sounds like your install did not run properly. I recommend you reinstall CrashPlan.

Comment: Yeah, apparently reinstalling did the job, thanks!